# Rails joining tables having has_many association

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have Student and Record table with a simple has_many :through association:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :records
end
```

I need to fetch all students details of MBA branch. I need  to assign result to a variable @students and need to access record of a student using

```
@students.each do |student|
   students.records.each do |record|
      ///
   end
end
```

That is I need to access has_many related class datas also into an object. How to write query for that. I am newbee in rails. Please help .Thanks in advance

Comment: You never accepted an answer of your previous questions :-/

Comment: My previous issue with rspec is not solved yet. I am looking for a solution for that too.

Comment: @AkhilSudhakaran: From where you are getting branch?

Comment: try this, @student = Student.includes(:records), Then do eaching on instance variable. This will save you from N+1 issue

Comment: can we add a where condition in it

Comment: Yes of course, let me know which condition you want

Comment: student.course = "MBA"

Comment: can we use something like this Student.includes(:records).includes(:marks).where(:course ="MCA"). Mark is another has_many association

Comment: please check my updated answer.

Comment: yes you can do that as well, Student.includes(:records, :marks).where(:course ="MCA")

Comment: is your issue is solved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
@student = Student.where("student.course = ?", "MBA").includes(:records)
```

Then do eaching on instance variable. This will save you from N+1 issue

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a has_many relation instead of has_many :through. Have you looked through the rails guides? There they describe how to fetch data from the database. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#read
Here is a more detailed reference on the has_many relation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference

Make sure you access student and not student**s** in the loop.

```
@students.each do |student|
  student.records.each do |record|
    ///
  end
end
```

Where is the MBA branch coming from? Is that another table?

You probably will end up with something like `@students = Student.where(branch_id: 1)`.
The ID 1 is just fictional but I'm guessing you have your branches in another table.